# How to use Kullback-Leiber divergence for discriminating 2 keywords

Tags: text-mining, kullback-leibler

I'm getting 500 tweets for each of the keywords K1 and K2 and I want to discriminate these 2 keywords with Kullback-Leiber Divergence formula.

I do normal text mining preprocessing such as removing stopwords, links, ... and then I get top 50 words for each keyword (excluding the keyword itself).

Now I am confused how to apply KL-D for discrimination.

- Should I do it only on the words that appear in both of the top50 or not?
- How will KL-D help to the discrimination? (As far as I understood we use it to find out how much information of K1 we can represent by using K2)
- I found [this tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/practical-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence-discrete-case-2/) but I'm not sure how to use it. In the tutorial, they have a vector of size 100 where [a,b,c] or [e,d] appears in different indexes of the vector but in my case, it is a totally different data structure.